# javascript two times using the same formule

Tags: javascript, jquery

why cant i use this formule twice?

```
main.espace = Math.floor(btn.margin + parseInt( ((main.width - main.rowWidth) / main.inRow)/2) );
```

in this content:

```
main.btnC.css({ 'margin-left': main.espace });
main.btnC.css({ 'margin-right': main.espace });
```

full script:
http://jsfiddle.net/ycHVx/

using the formule once:

```
main.btnC.css({ 'margin-left': main.espace });
main.btnC.css({ 'margin-right': otherFormule })
```

does works but if i use the same formule on the margin-right
doesn't work any more :(
im getting really stressed, please help me out or add me on social media to help please
fb: https://www.facebook.com/robin.timman?ref=tn_tnmn
twitter: https://twitter.com/RobinTimman

Comment: What do you mean, can't use the same formula twice?

Comment: Looks like a correctly configured jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/ycHVx/1/

Comment: What does not work exactly? You are referencing a variable, it is not magically going to lose its value in two lines.

Comment: Just so you know, in your JS Fiddle, you have these lines: `console.log(main.espace);` `console.log(main.espac);`. Notice that the second one says `main.espac` with no `e` on the end. Your console output will give you false information.

Comment: I get the white space at the right and slice it in the items per row, and want to add them (the half) add each side

Comment: yeah, i fixed that and that is not the problem

Comment: Also notice that you are using jQuery in your code, but your jsFiddle doesn't include the jQuery library (options on the upper left). Also, your appWidget object ends in a comma, which is bad syntax.

Comment: check: robintimman.com/test/ab/ for the real live script

Comment: I get this console error on your live site (in Firefox): `document.getElementsByClassName(...).style is undefined`

Answer (score 4):

You need to set a unit.

```
main.btnC.css({ 'margin-left': main.espace + "px"});
main.btnC.css({ 'margin-right': main.espace  + "px" });
```

better yet, combine them

```
main.btnC.css(
    {
        'margin-left': main.espace + "px",
        'margin-right': main.espace  + "px"
    }
);
```

Comment: still doesn't works :(, im getting really nervous :'( im stuck for 2 days

Comment: You could use camelCase to, IMO more readable: marginLeft: main.espace + "px",

Comment: What does not work exactly? When you inspect the element do you see the margins set. Are the margins block elements?

Comment: I get the white space at the right and slice it in the items per row, and want to add them (the half) add each side

Comment: I tested this on the live site and it works fine for me in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

```
main.btnC.css({ 'margin-left': main.espace, 'margin-right': main.espace });
```

Comment: How is this functionally any different?

Comment: I think what is happening is that you are adding the margin-left css, then when you do margin-right, you are resetting all of the css, so yours is only setting margin-right. If you're css() function appended CSS properties to the dom instead of just overwrote things, it'd work the same.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
 main.btnC.css({ 'margin-left': main.espace, 'margin-right': main.espace });
```

Comment: doesn't work, also tried but i tried using it only one time, then it works but for both it doesn't work